# How to identify entity from a the scenario below?

Tags: database

Here's the given problem:

1. Client wants to create a movie app
2. Different movie theatres can register to be on this app
3. Each theatre can input their different outlets
4. Each outlet can offer many movies.
5. Each movie can be cast in multiple outlets
6. Customer can view multiple movies to showtime
7. Each movie showtime can be viewed by multiple customers
8. One outlet will maintain multiple customers

With my limited knowledge, I can list out some of the possible Entities but I'm not confident or 100% sure if it's correct.

Identify the Entities :

1. Client
2. Customers
3. Movie Outlet
4. Movie Theatres
5. Movie Screenings
6. Showtime

I was wondering if Movie App is also an entity but for now I am guessing it is not. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You've overseen one major entity: Movies.

The "Movie App" is no entity, just replace with "the backend database".

Screening and showtime are probably the same thing?

Comment: 1) Client
2) Customers
3) Movie Outlets
4) Movie Theatres
5) Movies
6) Movie Showtimes
--------------------------------

This should be correct? Movie App is a noun but I don't have to include It right?

Comment: Without movies this all makes no sense. That's alike running a bank without money.

Comment: Should the "client" be added or the "Movie app"?